# RSpec return 404; Post to subdomain with JSON data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to send raw JSON within Request Rspec. (Because I tried it in Controller Rspec, but JSON data is not parsed in rails 4.2.)
Also I set up the subdomain **api**.

I always get `404`.

```
  describe "POST #create" do
    let(:json_body) do
      '{"foo":"foo_value", "bar":"bar_value", "baz":"baz_value"}'
    end
    it "returns not acceptable to non json content-type request" do
      post "/subscriptions" , json_body, { 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json', 'ACCEPT' => 'application/json' }
    end
```

Any ideas to fix this?

**UPDATE**

`config/routes.rb`

```
require 'api_constraints'

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/'  do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      resources :subscriptions, only: [:index, :new, :create]
    end
  end

end
```

**UPDATE2**

I set `host! 'api.localhost.local'` and then It works.
Ref: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1662
Ref2: http://www.screencast.com/t/nyZ2jKQi

```
Rspec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:all, type: :request) do
    host! 'api.lvh.me'
  end
end
```

Also I wonder why once I set the routes like this with a subdomain, it routes `<subdomain_name>.localhost.local:3000`as a default?

Comment: what if you go with json_body as `{foo: :foo, bar: :bar}`?

Comment: Can you post the specific part of your routes.rb, controller and how you set the subdomain?

Comment: Try `{ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json' }`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko sorry for the late reply. It returns `400`.

Comment: @zetetic What I got is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::SubscriptionsController, type: :request do
  let(:json_body) do
    '{:foo: 12, bar: 33}'
  end
  it "returns not acceptable to non json content-type request" do
    host! 'api.lvh.me' # <= This is needed because 'api' is the subdomain.
    headers = {
      "ACCEPT" => "application/json",     # This is what Rails 4 accepts
      'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'
    }

    post "/subscriptions", json_body.to_json ,headers
  end
end
```